# Symantec NetBackup restore - Incremental backup

Tags: symantec, netbackup

We are using Net Backup as a corporate solution.  Incremental backups are taken daily during the week and then a weekly backup is done at the weekend (Saturday).

My colleague has restored a folder to how it stood at 14:00 on a Tuesday.  The problem is that the restore is taking files from the weekend backup if they did not exist at that point in time of the restore.  For example, the folder we are restoring should look like this (this is how it looked on Tuesday at 14:00):

```
Folder1 (folder name)
Test.txt
Test1.txt
Test2.txt
```

The folder looked like this at the weekend when the full restore was done (even though it did exist at the weekend when the full backup ran):

```
Folder1 (folder name)
Test.txt
Test1.txt
Test2.txt
Test3.txt
```

The actual folder restored looks like this:

```
Folder1 (folder name)
Test.txt
Test1.txt
Test2.txt
Test3.txt
```

Test3.txt should not be restored because it did not exist at the point of the restore.  Is there a setting somewhere that we are missing.  The folder in question is 200GB - the example above is for simplification.  I realise this is a basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH31889.  There is a setting in Symantec Backup called True Image Restore.